# (n)DCG without true relevance scores

Tags: model-evaluation, ranking, information-retrieval

I have a search engine that returns results with a normalized score on the scale 0.0 to 1.0. Higher score means higher relevancy to the input query.

The ranked output scores look like this, e.g. [1.0, 0.5, 0.1] vs [0.6, 0.5, 0.4] for k=3.

Assuming that these scores are indeed correct, I want to measure the quality of the results for a given query. The intuition is that if the collection contains very relevant results for a query, the aggregated score for the top k results should be high, whereas the score should be low if the collection has fewer good results.

Following that intuition, good results on the top ranks should be emphasized, whereas lower ranks are less important. [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain) seems to be a good candidate as it weighs in the rank: [image: formula]

However, when looking at common implementations of (n)DCG, the output rankings are always compared against the true scores, for instance in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.dcg_score.html#sklearn-metrics-dcg-score).

Comparing against the true relevancy clearly makes sense for evaluating an information retrieval system against a manually labeled dataset. However, how does this fit into the DCG formula above? The formula only takes a single ranking into account.

So my questions are:

- How is DCG used to compare an output ranking against a "true" ranking?
- Does the DCG score as outlined above, for a single ranking, make sense to indicate the quality of the results for a query?
- Bonus question: can I use e.g. the (n)DCG implementation of scikit-learn without true scores?

Answer (score 0):

Consider we have 3 articles with true relevance scores as `[10, 7, 2]`, and our search engine gave them predicted scores as `[0.4, 0.7, 0.2]`. In this case, we are ranking the $2^{nd}$ article first, followed by the $1^{st}$ and then the $3^{rd}$ at last. In other words, the true relevance scores (each representing one article) are re-ordered by the search engine into `[7, 10, 2]`.

The following answer will be based on this `[7, 10, 2]` result.

> How is DCG used to compare an output ranking against a "true" ranking?

by $DCG \over idealDCG$ [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain#Normalized_DCG)

For example, normalized DCG of `[7, 10, 2]` is DCG of `[7, 10, 2]` divided by DCG of `[10, 7, 2]`

> Does the DCG score as outlined above, for a single ranking, make sense to indicate the quality of the results for a query?

Given that you said

> The intuition is that if the collection contains very relevant results for a query, the aggregated score for the top k results should be high, whereas the score should be low if the collection has fewer good results.

I think you don't care the ordering, so my answer is No. You use DCG when you specifically care about the ordering. Note that the denominator of the DCG penalize the score ranked later, which means you have a higher DCG if you rank your results by the scores.

High DCG: `[10, 7, 2]`
Low DCG: `[7, 10, 2]`
Lowest DCG: `[2, 7, 10]`

Certainly the absolute score values also impact the DCG such that DCG of `[10, 7, 2]` is better than DCG of `[3, 2, 1]`, ***but*** DCG of `[2, 7, 10]` is also worse than `[10, 7, 2]`. In this case, is DCG still your choice?

> Bonus question: can I use e.g. the (n)DCG implementation of scikit-learn without true scores?

Yes for DCG. You can pass the same value for both `y_true` and `y_score` and this is equivalent to saying that your search engine always predicts the ordering correctly. But this is not the right way to use it.

**Summary**:
DCG is designed for ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
After looking at the sklearn implementations of (n)DCG, I am still not clear about the comparison part. In sklearn, both DCG and nDCG take a `y_true` and a `y_score` argument, whereas your description reads like nDCG was the use case for comparing a DCG score against a "gold standard".

Comment: To get a DCG of a sequence, you need two pieces of information. #1 the order #2 the true score. `y_score` gives you #1, `y_true` gives you #2. `y_score` is assigned by your search engine, it talks about the order ONLY: the higher the score, the higher the order should be. `y_true` is the true relevance (not predicted by your search engine). Therefore you need both for DCG. For nDCG, the only new thing it needs to calculate is the ideal-DCG, ofcourse it also requires the two pieces of information, but `y_true` alone is enough, therefore, nDCG still just requires the same `y_true` and `y_score`.

Comment: @Carsten, I have modified my answer, and I hope this will be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, but this one piece is still missing: you were referring to nDCG for normalising the DCG score against an ideal DCG score. However, you can pass a `true_score` to the `dcg_score()` function as well. In this case, how does `true_score` fit into the DCG formula (not nDCG!)?

Comment: Hey @Carsten, I have been having a doubt but I want to verify it with you (please don't mind), the `rel` that is in the numerator of the equation you shown in your question, it should be for the `true_score` but not your search engine's predicted score. You agree?

Comment: $rel_i$ is the `true_score` of the $i$th-ranked article.

Comment: Search engine's score only determines the $i$ for each of the articles.

Comment: I think `rel_i` it is the score as listed in the output: e.g. for `y_score = [1.0, 0.5, 0.4]`, these are the values for `rel_1`, `rel 2`, `rel_3`. That is exactly why I am not sure where to put the `y_true` values in the equation. At the same time, if `rel_i` was referring to the `y_true`, where would the `y_score` belong?

Comment: Ok, got it now. This assumes a fixed list of scores in which only the _ranking_ between ideal/true and actual scores can differ.

Comment: Yes! One more example: the true relevance score for article A, B, C is 10, 7, 3 respectively. The search engine score for article A, B, C is 0.5, 0.2, 0.7. Therefore, the ranking of the articles is C, A, B. I like to present this ordering in terms of their true score, so that will be 3, 10, 7. So the DCG will be $\frac{2^3 - 1}{log_2 (1+1)} + \frac{2^{10} - 1}{log_2 (1+2)} + \frac{2^7 - 1}{log_2 (1+3)}$

Comment: Btw, you gotta check the sklearn implementation, because I think it uses the first DCG form instead of the second one which are shown in this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain#Discounted_Cumulative_Gain

Comment: I think the two forms are equivalent, the reformulation is just about intelligibility.